Ubuntu 24.04 and Intel MiPi camera not working
I have Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 10 with Ubuntu 24.04LTS and 6.8.0-38-generic stock kernel installed. Using apt I've installed intel-usbio-dkms and then all four repositories as mentioned on https://github.com/intel/ipu6-drivers?tab=readme-ov-file
For ipu6-drivers I decided to use DKMS method, it built and loaded without any issues:
# dkms status
ipu6-drivers/0.0.0, 6.8.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed
usbio-drivers/0~git202312141918.78ffb706-0ubuntu2, 6.8.0-38-generic, x86_64: installed

I've also tried Intel Integrated Image Processing Unit 6 driver from Additional drivers but it didn't make any difference except ipu6-drivers didn't build because it was already provided.
# cat /sys/class/video4linux/*/name
Intel IPU6 CSI-2 0
Intel IPU6 CSI2 BE SOC 2
Intel IPU6 CSI2 BE SOC 3
Intel IPU6 CSI2 BE SOC 4
Intel IPU6 CSI2 BE SOC 5
Intel IPU6 CSI2 BE SOC 6
Intel IPU6 CSI2 BE SOC 7
ov2740 13-0036
Intel IPU6 CSI-2 1
Intel IPU6 CSI-2 2
Intel IPU6 CSI-2 3
Intel IPU6 CSI-2 4
Intel IPU6 CSI-2 5
Intel IPU6 CSI-2 6
Intel IPU6 CSI-2 7
Intel IPU6 CSI2 BE SOC 0
Intel IPU6 CSI2 BE SOC 1
Intel IPU6 BE SOC capture 0
Intel IPU6 BE SOC capture 1
Intel IPU6 BE SOC capture 2
Intel IPU6 BE SOC capture 3
Intel IPU6 BE SOC capture 4
Intel IPU6 BE SOC capture 5
Intel IPU6 BE SOC capture 6
Intel IPU6 BE SOC capture 7

# lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-U15 Host and DRAM Controller (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-UP3 GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 0c)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Innovation Platform Framework Processor Participant (rev 04)
00:05.0 Multimedia controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake Imaging Signal Processor (rev 04)
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x4 Controller #0 (rev 04)
00:07.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #0 (rev 04)
00:07.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev 04)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation 12th Gen Core Processor Gaussian & Neural Accelerator (rev 04)
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Platform Monitoring Technology (rev 01)
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 04)
00:0d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #0 (rev 04)
00:0d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 NHI #1 (rev 04)
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 01)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
00:19.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 51b8 (rev 01)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH eSPI Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller PM9A1/PM9A3/980PRO
08:00.0 Wireless controller [0d40]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 4d75 (rev 01)

# lsusb 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 06cb:00fc Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8086:0b63 Intel Corp. USB Bridge
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. AX211 Bluetooth
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub

Did I miss something?

Please, insert output of lsusb

@Mahler added as requested

I think kernel doesn't detect webcam. Otherwise, it should be listed in 'lsusb'.

This is MiPi not USB.

This is a known issue. You can try the drivers on this page:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IntelMIPICamera

The Intel IPU6 driver still doesn't work for me, but the HAL IPU6 library works for me now on my Dell XPS 9320:

